# Compare before column in before row with next column in next row

Tags: sql, oracle

My code is :

```
with x as 
(
    select 1 col from dual union all
    select 2 col from dual union all
    select 8 col from dual union all
    select 4 col from dual union all
    select 3 col from dual union all
    select 2 col from dual
)
select col col1, col col2, col col3, rownum
from x 
where col2.ROWNUM > col1.ROWNUM -1 
  and col2.ROWNUM > col3ROWNUM +1 ;
```

I want to compare `col2.ROWNUM > col1.ROWNUM -1 and col2.ROWNUM > col3ROWNUM + 1` but that doesn't work and I got an error

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
> 01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 10 Column: 13

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks you got something wrong.

Result of that CTE is a single-column *table* whose only column is named `col`. There are no other columns.

```
SQL> with x as (
  2  select 1 col from dual union all  --> in UNION, all columns are
  3  select 2 col from dual union all      named by column name(s) from the 
  4  select 8 col from dual union all      first SELECT statement
  5  select 4 col from dual union all
  6  select 3 col from dual union all
  7  select 2 col from dual)
  8  select x.*, rownum
  9  from x;

       COL     ROWNUM
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         8          3
         4          4
         3          5
         2          6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Therefore, `where` clause you wrote doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you should explain what you really have, rules that should be applied to source data and result you'd like to get.

---

Based on text you put into the title:

> compare before column in before row with next column in next row

maybe you'd be interested in `lag` and `lead` analytic functions which then let you *compare* values in adjacent rows (pay attention to `NULL` values; I didn't). For example:

```
SQL> with x as (
  2    select 1 col from dual union all
  3    select 2 col from dual union all
  4    select 8 col from dual union all
  5    select 4 col from dual union all
  6    select 3 col from dual union all
  7    select 2 col from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10    (select col,
 11            rownum as rn
 12     from x
 13    ),
 14  temp2 as
 15    (select
 16       rn,
 17       col as this_row,
 18       lag(col)  over (order by rn) as previous_row,
 19       lead(col) over (order by rn) as next_row
 20     from temp
 21    )
 22  select this_row,
 23    previous_row,
 24    next_row,
 25    --
 26    case when this_row < previous_row then 'This < previous'
 27         when this_row < next_row     then 'This < next'
 28         else 'something else'
 29    end as result
 30  from temp2
 31  order by rn;
```

Result:

```
  THIS_ROW PREVIOUS_ROW   NEXT_ROW RESULT
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------------
         1                       2 This < next
         2            1          8 This < next
         8            2          4 something else
         4            8          3 This < previous
         3            4          2 This < previous
         2            3            This < previous

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, results sets have a non-deterministic order (i.e. they are unordered) unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore, if you have a physical table, you need another column to provide the order (rather than relying on the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column, which may result in unexpected behaviour):

```sql
CREATE TABLE x (order_id, col) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to find the rows that go up in succession, then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   x
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY order_id
  MEASURES
    any_row.col     AS col1,
    FIRST(up.col)   AS col2,
    LAST(up.col)    AS col3,
    FIRST(order_id) AS start_order_id
  PATTERN ( any_row up{2} )
  DEFINE up AS ( col > PREV(col) )
)
```

or the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT col AS col1,
         LEAD(col, 1) OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS col2,
         LEAD(col, 2) OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS col3,
         order_id
  FROM   x
)
WHERE  col2 > col1
AND    col3 > col2;
```

Which both output:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | START_ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jy_Uzxkl)

Answer (score 0):

Use lead or lag functions. But, please, do not use rownum for such purposes.
Rownum indicates simply the order in which a row was found in the database and cannot be used for other purposes except limiting the number of rows fetched, like where rownum<=1 to be certain you won't get a too_many_rows exception, for instance. Still, if in a query you do fetch the pseud-column rownum, give it an alias so that you may use that value later on.
Moreover, what is supposed to mean col2.ROWNUM or col1.ROWNUM? That is not clear. col1 and col2 are two columns, which do not have the attribute rownum.
Something that may help in the future for analytic queries:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

And, if you wish to get a working SQL, please explain clearly what you wish to achieve, for I haven't really understood what that code is intended to do.

A way you may use rownum without getting errors:

```
with x as (
select 1 col from dual union all
select 2 col from dual union all
select 8 col from dual union all
select 4 col from dual union all
select 3 col from dual union all
select 2 col from dual)
```

,x2 as (
select col col1 ,col col2, col col3 ,rownum rn
from x
)
select *
from x2
where rn between 2 and 3 --- rownum cannot be used in such a
condition!!!
;

Or, to be certain you get only the first row from a table satisfying a given condition:

```
select x_col1, x_col2 into v_col1, v_col2
from x_table
where ... --- logical conditions
  and rownum<=1; --- rownum <= 1 avoids too_many_rows_exception if several rows satisfy the logical conditions given before
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to find the rows where the value of the column is bigger than it is in both - the previous and next row. If so, you could try this:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (ID, COL) AS    -- Sample data (ID column is just to preserve order of the rows)
      (
          Select 1, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 8 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 4 From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 6, 2 From DUAL
      )
Select    ID, COL, CASE WHEN COL > LAG(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ID) And COL > LEAD(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ID) THEN 'YES' END "BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT"
From      tbl
Order By  ID

        ID        COL BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT
---------- ---------- -------------------------
         1          1                           
         2          2                           
         3          8 YES                       
         4          4                           
         5          3                           
         6          2
```

... with a bit different sample data this will find the other row(s) that satisfy the condition ...

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (ID, COL) AS    -- Sample data (ID column is just to preserve order of the rows)
      (
          Select 1, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 8 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 4 From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 5 From Dual Union All   -- value of COL changed from 3 to 5
          Select 6, 2 From DUAL
      )
Select    ID, COL, CASE WHEN COL > LAG(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ID) And COL > LEAD(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ID) THEN 'YES' END "BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT"
From      tbl
Order By  ID

        ID        COL BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT
---------- ---------- -------------------------
         1          1                           
         2          2                           
         3          8 YES                       
         4          4                           
         5          5 YES                       
         6          2
```

OR without ID - using ROWNUM (as in your question), - **not adviseable**, though...

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (COL) AS    -- Sample data (without ID column)
      (
          Select 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 8 From Dual Union All
          Select 4 From Dual Union All
          Select 5 From Dual Union All   
          Select 2 From DUAL
      )
Select    COL, CASE WHEN COL > LAG(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ROWNUM) And COL > LEAD(COL, 1) OVER(Order By ROWNUM) THEN 'YES' END "BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT"
From      tbl

       COL BIGGER_THAN_PREV_AND_NEXT
---------- -------------------------
         1                           
         2                           
         8 YES                       
         4                           
         5 YES                       
         2
```

Any Order By clause added to the query could change the ROWNUM values and the result...

Comment: @d r Oh ,my God exactly you understand my question correctly , thank s a lot , it is hard to me to explain correctly  to English Language , Thank you a lot , I am new in oracle , my problem solved .